# iOS BarButton padding and font size

Tags: ios, xcode

i have this storyboard and a text in the center , how can i

- Move that text in the height center of the nav bar
- Change the font size of the bar button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is that a UINavigationBar? And I'm assuming your title is nil, and "TEXT" is a UIBarButtonItem? You can change the offset of a bar button with `setTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:`.

But I don't think you can easily change the font size. You may need to substitute in a view with `initWithCustomView:`. This might be an easier way to adjust the vertical positioning at the same time.